How to get the geojson of a layer from the ArcGIS API instead of PNG images?
I'm trying to get the geojson of the layers at this interactive ArcGIS map:
https://cherwell.maps.arcgis.com/apps/webappviewer/index.html?id=c4ffa2d7d99949b185c6d622a0f9d8ab
Looking at the network requests I can see that it is pulling lots of png images like this one and stitching them together to create the map.
https://utility.arcgis.com/usrsvcs/servers/f6c1af543e1e42a2b3b73a239e134e49/rest/services/Public_Map_Services/Cherwell_Public_Local_Plan_Partial_Review_2020/MapServer/export?dpi=96&transparent=true&format=png32&layers=show%3A1%2C3%2C5%2C7%2C9%2C11%2C12%2C14%2C15%2C17%2C18%2C20%2C21%2C23%2C24%2C25%2C26%2C27%2C28%2C29%2C30%2C31%2C32%2C33%2C34&bbox=439822.96643358556%2C200746.08424474625%2C489942.9664256926%2C256410.08423598023&bboxSR=27700&imageSR=27700&size=895%2C994&f=image

Is there an alternative API that would get me the geojson for the layers? Or has this been deliberately locked down to make this impossible?

Ask for a WFS endpoint
